# SQL JOIN with date 'categories'

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, syntax

I am trying to create a query that groups members into children and adults:

mysql tickets:

```
|ticket_id|ticket_no|
|    1    | 123456  |
```

mysql members:

```
|member_id|ticket_no|  name  |    dob     |
|    1    | 123456  | edward | 2010-03-05 | //child
|    2    | 123456  | karen  | 1965-03-05 | //adult
```

html output:

```
|ticket_no|Adult Names|Children Names|
| 123456  |   karen   |    edward    |
```

I would like to do it with a join query really and output it in a loop as a row.
This is just an example:

```
SELECT t.*, m.*
FROM (`tickets` t)
JOIN(`members` m)
    ON(m.`ticket_no` = t.`ticket_no`)
    (SELECT m.`name` FROM m WHERE m.`dob` BETWEEN {$cStart} AND {$cEnd}) as children
    (SELECT m.`name` FROM m WHERE m.`dob` BETWEEN {$aStart} AND {$aEnd}) as adults
ORDER BY t.`ticket_no`
```

Any help greatly appreciated.

Working SQL:

```
        SELECT t.*,
        CASE
            WHEN m.`dob`
                BETWEEN '{$datetime['start']}'
                AND '{$datetime['end']}'
            THEN m.`name`
        END AS ChildName
        FROM `tickets` t
        JOIN (`members` m)
            ON (m.`ticket_no` = t.`ticket_no`)
        ORDER BY t.`ticket_no`
```

Comment: There is not any field in 'members' which defines that member is a child or parent. How can you know that edward is children and karen is adult through database table?

Comment: The DOB field should decide whether the person is either an adult or child (above or below 18 years old)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this. Just pass appropriate date range in variables you are using

```
    SELECT t.ticket_no,
    case when m.`dob` BETWEEN {$aStart} AND {$aEnd} then m.name  end as AdultName,
 case when m.`dob` BETWEEN {$cStart} AND {$cEnd} then m.name end as ChildName
     FROM (`tickets` t)
    JOIN(`members` m)
        ON(m.`ticket_no` = t.`ticket_no`)
    ORDER BY t.`ticket_no`
```

Comment: `then m.name as AdultName end`... that's a wrong syntax I believe

Comment: I tried this, as @Rahul noted it threw a syntax error. I checked the manual and the syntax is correct - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case.html. Please see my update.

Comment: Hi, this sorts the syntax error but now ChildName = NULL. See my edit

Comment: Apologies, the between clause is not being met because I had mssed out the comas around the values `'{$aStart}'` etc.